# How can I use a textbox to get my program to calculate points for my project reworded

Tags: java, string

My Project involves a user to create a word, where the user is given 10 randomly generated letters. The user will enter their word in a text box. Points will be awarded for each letter used. I don't know how to calculate the points, given that each letter is worth different points (the letter a=2 points, the letter j = 4 points and so on). My question is how can i do that?

Comment: a textbox will be used for the user to enter their word

Comment: please help with some sample

Comment: Some kind of `Map` maybe

Comment: The title for your question indicates to me that you don't have a good grasp of the problem that you're trying to solve.  I believe you wish to know how to map individual characters from a String to some corresponding integer value.  This has nothing to do with TextBox controls.  You'll likely get more (and better) answers if you rephrase your question.

Comment: Okay so here is my question reworded.

Comment: My Project involves a user to create a word, where the user is given 10 randomly generated letters. The user will enter their word in a text box. Points will be awarded for each letter used. I don't know how to calculate the points, given that each letter is worth different points (the letter a=2 points, the letter j = 4 points and so on). My question is how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have every word as a `String`, then all you have to do is convert each letter to its integer value with a method that you'll have to create. You didn't specify what score you wanted your characters to have, but you're probably wanting something using `Character.getNumericValue(letter)`. For instance,

```
public int letterScore(char letter) {
    final int LETTER_OFFSET = 9;
    int score = Character.getNumericValue(letter);
    score -= LETTER_OFFSET;
    return score;
}
```

You didn't specify what you wanted your scores of each letter to be, so you would have to tweak this function to fit the exact output you wanted. Combining this and a loop that considers the score of each `char letter = word.charAt(index)`, you'll get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the value of the text field on a String variable, let's call it data:

```
int totalScore = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    totalScore+= letterScore(data.charAt(i));
}
```

Then you need your `letterScore` to compute the scores for each letter.

This could look something like:

```
public int letterScore(char letter){
    switch (letter) {
      case 'a':
      case 'e':
      case 'i':
        return 1;
        break;
      case 'm': 
      case 'n': 
        return 2;
        break;
      default:
            // This is used for any other letter
            return 3;
            break;
    }
```